# Sub Menu with ul li hover becomes transparent

Tags: css

I have developed a simple menu using ul li and a tag and have added css style (standards used in my organization). But when I hover on the menu the submenu is becoming transparent by default. The css has some basic stuff and ideally this should not happen. Please direct me where Iam going wrong. Please see the code in this link  [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/5196/)  . Below is some portion of the code.

```
 div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited {
        background-color: blue;
        font-family: "Arial";
        font-size: 12px;
        border: 1px Green solid;
        color: #ffffff;
        display: block;
        line-height: 1.35em;
        padding: 4px 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        white-space: nowrap;
        z-index: 999;
    }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It's not transparent, it's just positioned *under* other page elements.

This is all you're missing:

```
.MenubarDiv {
    position:relative;   /* this guy */
```

**[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/5197/)**